# Why does one of these onClickListerners work but not the other?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button

The startBubbles works. The checker does not. I can post the `setAll()` and `countDown.start()`, if you want, but as I said, that all works. Is there any reason checker shouldn't work?

```
OnClickListener startBubbles = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        setAll();
        countDown.start();
    }

};

OnClickListener checker = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String choice = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
        if(choice.equals(matcher.getText().toString())){
            a++;
            setAll();
        }else {
            ((Button)v).setText("Wrong!");
        }

    }

};
```

Everything used to work, but then I tried to make some changes(for the better), couldn't, and tried to back track. Been sorting out the problems for an hour. Everything is alright but this.

And there's no errors showing up in the logcat.

Comment: So what happens when you click `checker`? nothing at all?

Comment: You probably commented out or accidentally removed your `object.setOnClickListener(checker);` line.

Comment: @Szymon yeah, nothing

Comment: @pasta12 no, all that's alright

Comment: You're sure. And you're sure you set it to the correct object and are clicking the correct object. Because if you do a log in checker and get nothing that says to me you hooked it up wrong.

Comment: put breakpoints on these two listeners and debug to check whether they are called or not. If not then there is something wrong where you have attached these click listeners to your view.

Comment: do you see "Wrong" printed when you use checker at all?

Answer (score 0):

Creating two `OnClickListener` objects is inefficient. I generally try to avoid unnecessary creation of objects where possible.

A common pattern I use is to make the `Activity` class implement `OnClickListener`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button button1; 
    private Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      button1.setOnClickListener(this);
      button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
      button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if (v == button1) {
        // do something
      }
      else if (v == button2) {
        // do something else
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you didin't specify the button on wich the onClick is linked try this

```
yourButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAll();
    countDown.start();
                        }
                    });
```